# Sharing variables when parallel processing

Tags: sas

I have setup a process that parallel processes 8 programs to pull a lot of data.  However, I have to maintain all of the variables in each one going forward (this is a monthly thing).

Is there a way to create 1 master program with all of the variables and share them across programs when running?  I understand each program uses its own instance of SAS so I am thinking no.

Comment: The programs can share a library.

Comment: hmmm...so I can create a permanent library (MYLIB) and assign a bunch of %let variables (MONTH, etc).  How do I call them in my other programs?  &MYLIB.MONTH?

Comment: Describe the variables in each of the 8 programs, and what you want as the final result.  %LET variables are macro variables and can be considered more a parameters for controlling flow, code generation and data filtering values.  Do you want to each of the 8 program to use the same macro variable values ?

Comment: I work for a data company and I am pulling down millions of records.  I have to split the pulls into 8 different programs by product type so I do need all 8 programs to use the same %Let MONTH variable.  I would love to do this once but it is more annoying than deal breaking if I can't.

Comment: Store the parameter values, like MONTH, in a dataset that is in the shared library.  Each branch can then convert the value(s) from the parameter dataset into macro variable(s) if that helps the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly notice, the different SAS programs do not share variables automatically, but you can pass them explicitly:

- By passing them through environment variables (this is especially useful when you have few parameters, like the report date).

  - The launcher program in this case can be a simple shell script, e.g. in *nix:

    ```
    export REPORT_DATE=20190701
    sas -sysin program_a.sas
    ```
  - Or, from SAS, you can use `systask command` to execute the child SAS session
  - From the child session you can retrieve the parameter value via `%sysget`:

    ```
    %let REPORT_DATE = %sysget(REPORT_DATE);
    ```
- As suggested in the comments, by storing the parameters in a shared location (e.g. in a dataset).

  - In the parent session:

    ```
    data sharedlib.params;
        REPORT_DATE = "&REPORT_DATE";
    run;
    ```
  - In the child session:

    ```
    proc sql noprint;
        select REPORT_DATE /*format XXX. as necessary*/ into :REPORT_DATE
        from sharedlib.params;
    quit;
    ```
- If you use SAS/CONNECT to manage the child sessions (i.e. `signon` and `rsubmit`), you can pass the variables via `%sysrput`